# Sonatype Nexus Private Repository unable to prompt for username and password in runtime while pulling the package using cli

Tags: authentication, deb, sonatype, nexus3, private-repository

I want to set up an authentication method in the private repository (nexus oss 3.62) where whenever a user tries to pull package via the cli precisely it should ask for a username and password.
I am able to achieve this by passing username and password in URl
**deb https://username:passwd@URL_OF_PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_NEXUS/repository/package.**
but I want to figure out a way to pass it in runtime without providing it in url(similar to that when we do docker login it prompts for username and password).
example for what i'm trying to achieve:
deb https://URL_OF_PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_NEXUS/repository it should prompt for
username:
passwd:
and later let users to pull package if they are authorized.